# How to reduce bundle size of the webpack build for a react application?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working on a React application and uses Webpack to create bundle.js file. Even though my application is very simple bundle.js file size is around 11MB.

When I analyze the bundle file with https://webpack.github.io/analyse/, more than 1000 packages are included in the bundle.js. Some of those packages are defined in devDependencies section of the package.json file.

Therefore I am looking for answers to following questions.
Is there a way to reduce file size of the webpack compilation?
Does webpack include devDependencies modules in final bundle.js?

Comment: It depends on your _webpack.config_ file, could you add/show it for us?

Comment: And you seem to have a lot of packages in your package.json. Do you need all of them?

Comment: Thanx for the reply. solved. change devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' to  devtool: 'cheap-source-map' in webpack config file now it is 1MB.

Answer (score 2):

change devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' to devtool: 'cheap-source-map' in webpack config. beacause webpack -p doesnot accept cheap-module-eval-source-map

Answer (score 1):

I have webpack 6.0.1. In addition to usual webpack.config.js settings I can suggest the following optimization model (webpack.config.js production mode). For more info see the [optimization](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/), [mode configuration](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/) and comments related to plugins at the bottom:

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  ...
  plugins : [
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') }),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
      hashFunction: 'sha256',
      hashDigest: 'hex',
      hashDigestLength: 4
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  ],

  ...

  optimization: {
    namedModules: false,
    namedChunks: false,
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    flagIncludedChunks: true,
    occurrenceOrder: true,
    sideEffects: true,
    usedExports: true,
    concatenateModules: true,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'all'
        }
      },
      minSize: 30000,
      maxAsyncRequests: 5,
      maxAsyncRequests: 3,      
    },
    noEmitOnErrors: true,
    minimize: true, 
    minimizer: [
      // we specify a custom UglifyJsPlugin here to get source maps in production
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: false,
          ecma: 6,
          mangle: true
        },
        sourceMap: true
      })
    ],
    removeAvailableModules: true,
    removeEmptyChunks: true,
    mergeDuplicateChunks: true,    
  },
...
}
```

Comments:

1. webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin() - concatenate the scope
   of all your modules into one closure and allow for your code to have
   a faster execution time in the browser
2. webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin() - cause hashes to be based on the
   relative path of the module, generating a four character string as
   the module id
3. webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin() - vary the
   distribution of the ids to get the smallest id length for often used
   ids
4. webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin() - skip the emitting phase
   whenever there are errors while compiling. This ensures that no
   assets are emitted that include errors